# Two questions about iphone threading

Tags: iphone, multithreading, gps

How to create a NSThread for Iphone GPS

Comment: Is this homework? You should tag it as such if so...

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. It has to do with processor local caches (data/code might still be cached) and local memory (in NUMA aware systems)
2. I suggest performing some Googling, especially considering the NUMA (and `numactl`) case in Linux.